Angular 18 mat-table with border radius and row-hover
Version: angular and angular/material 18.2.8.
I currently implemented my tables like this:
styles.scss
table {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.table-card {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

This works for a mat-table with a border radius, but is probably not a good solution.
Now, I want to add a row hover effect:
tr:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

This also works, however, for the last- and header-row it does not take the border-radius and padding into account since those are defined on the table-card.
My tables are really simple:
 <div class="table-card" *ngIf="dataSource.data.length > 0">
  <table mat-table matSort matSortActive="name" matSortDirection="asc" [dataSource]="dataSource">
...

Also using
.mat-row:hover {
  background-color: red!important;
}

did not work for me yet.
What is the proper way to do a mat-table with border radius and a row-hover effect?
